# What is latest version available of openCV for android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, native

Which one is latest version of OpenCV V-2.4.13(2016-05-19) or v-3.1(2015-12-21)

Comment: very simple first there is `year` difference and visit this : http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Comment: Dear IronMan see there v.2.4 says (2016-05-19) and v.3.1 says(2015-12-21) logically 3.1 should be latest but see the date its 2015-12-21.

Comment: *logically 3.1 should be latest* ... no ... both branches are still developed ... so 2.4.13 is newest for 2.x branch and 3.1 is newest for 3.x branch

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but still the latest one is the 2.4.13. It depends which branch you want 2x or 3x. For 3x the latest one is 3.1